What is the solution/protocol to bypass Oracle database installer issues (INS-*****) in a development environment?
I am trying to install 19c x86-64 on RHEL 9 in a development environment, but am facing issues while running the Installer with a few INS warnings/errors. Here is what I have done so far:
Ran the pre-installer (oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-1.el9.x86_64.rpm)
Downloaded the zip to a path inside /u01 (can't do rpm because VM was configured to install on /u01 partition)
As the oracle user, extracted the zip to /dbhome_1
Updated the CV file from OEL5 to OEL7.8 (INS-08101)
Ran the install as ./run installer -ignoreInternalDriverError to bypass INS-30060 Check for group existence failed.
Unfortunately now it is failing again with the error "Error in invoking target ‘libasm***’ of makefile ‘/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db home_1/rdbms/lib/ins_rdbms.mk’.
Could this be that I need to apply a relevant patch? Which specific patches should I ask for? This is a development environment, and I do not have the support credentials to see which patch or to download it. Please advise, and thank you for reading through this post.
Again, in summary, below are the steps I have taken:

Ran the pre-installer rpm as per the above.
Downloaded zip to /u01 path.
As Oracle user, unzipped to the database home.
Changed the OEL in the cv file (INS-08101).
Ran the executable with the --ignoreInternalDriverError (INS-30060).
After the pre-installer check and during install now it is failing with the above mentioned error.

